# Detect text on UIview with touch event

Tags: iphone, text, uiview, detect, quartz-2d

I need to detect the text/glyph drawn on View through quartz 2d programming on touch event.
Is it possible to get the text/glyph from touch points on View.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by getting text on touching the view?

Comment: @balncos thanks for reply. By getting the text I mean I have one pdf and I want the character on the pdf page where my finger is placed on the screen. Is it possible ?

Comment: You didn't mention 'pdf' anywhere in your question. Pdf is altogether different case in getting character by touch input and its quite difficult. So is it a pdf or simple text container on View?

Comment: It's pdf.. But will be great enough of you if u can at least guide that from where can i start .. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have researched according to your needs. What you need is a combination of idea that how to get pdf coordinates and then your character out of it.

Use `CGPDFDocument`, `CGPDFScanner` and `CGPDFPage` to scan the contents of the pdf into `NSString`. Then use `NSString` functions to find the text on that page. If multiple pages are there then you will want to store page numbers also.

This link will give you idea about how to convert pdf coordinates to iOS coordinates to get your touch point. Check out first two answers in it. 
[Converting pdf to iOS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045587/how-to-get-actual-pdf-page-size-in-ipad?lq=1)